# ¿Existe alguna manera en la cual se pueda accionar funciones de un objeto al detectarlo con un Raycast2d en Unity?

Tags: unity, unity2d

Estoy intentando accionar una función de un objeto mediante la deteccion por raycast, es decir yo presiono con el mouse en la pantalla, creo un Raycast2D y detecto si colisione con un objeto 2D, y si eso pasa accionar una función dentro de ese objeto, por poner un ejemplo : cambiar_color(), destruir_objeto(), etc.
Desde ya muchas gracias por su atención.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si que se puede, una vez tengas almacenada la información del Raycast puedes utilizar `SendMessage("nombre_funcion")` para ejecutar una función que esté en el Script del objeto con el que has colisionado. Ojo, tendrás que comprobar primero que el objeto con el que ha colisionado tu Raycast es el objeto que contiene dicha función a la que quieres llamar, ya que si no te lanzará una Excepción.

Si compartes el código donde implementas tu Raycast2D podría ponerte un ejemplo más concreto, pero ahí va un ejemplo de uso general:

```
//Al hacer click primario instanciamos un Raycast2D
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0)){

    //La información del collider que ha entrado en colisión con el Raycast2D se almacena en la variable hit
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position , Vector2.right);

    //Si el Raycast2D colisiona con un gameobject cuyo Tag sea Enemigo, llamamos a una función que se encuentra dentro de su Script
    if (hit != null && hit.transform.gameObject.tag == "Enemigo"){
        hit.transform.gameObject.SendMessage("cambiar_color");
    }
}
```

Comment: ah joya, muchas gracias por responder la duda, la realidad es que estoy tratando de hacer un metodo para manejar controles para un juego mobile y lo habia hecho con las herramientas de unity, y despues probé con raycast, pero no fueron pruebas cuyos resultados me agradaron, igualmente gracias por responder